# Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ctx.portfolios[0].portfolioInfo') in Vue

Tags: vue.js, async-await

Getting this error after changing data file from static file (portfolio.json) to db.

```
<template>
  <section class="home-sect">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label for="portTitle"> Portfolio Title linked to:</label>
        <input
          type="text" name="portTitle" id="portTitle"
          :value="portfolios[0].portfolioInfo.portfolioTitle"
        />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="portLink"> Portfolio Number Being linked:</label>
        <input
          type="text" name="portLink" id="portLink"
          :value="portfolios[0].portfolioInfo.portfolioLink"
        />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="siteFooter"> Site Footer:</label>
        <input
          type="text" name="siteFooter" id="siteFooter"
          :value="portfolios[0].portfolioInfo.siteFooter"
        />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="heroTitle"> Title of hero image:</label>
        <input
          type="text" name="heroTitle" id="heroTitle"
          :value="portfolios[0].portfolioPics[0].thumbnail.title"
        />
      </li>
      <li>
        Url of hero image
        <input
          type="text" name="" id=""
          :value="portfolios[0].portfolioPics[0].thumbnail.image"
        /><img src="" alt="" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</template>

<script lang="js">

// import portfolios from "../assets/portfolio.json";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "EditHome",
  data() {
    return {
      portfolios: [],
    };
  },
  async created() {
    try {
      const result = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3010/portfolios`);
      const data = result.data;
      this.portfolios = data;
      console.log("EditHome portfolios[0] title ", this.portfolios[0].portfolioInfo.portfolioTitle);
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
    // this.portfolios = portfolios;
  },
};
</script>
```

I can see from the console log that this.portfolios[0].portfolioInfo.portfolioTitle has the correct value when accessing from db, but there is an error when attempting to render the value in the template.

Since this worked when I was defining portfolios from a static file, there is something wrong with the way I am handling the data, but currently at a loss identifying what.

If I comment out the db access and bring in the data via an import, all works fine.

Comment: It looks like you are accessing `portfolios[0]` even before the request finishes and the array is empty.

Comment: Of course! Added an isLoaded variable managed in created and added a v-if to control rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I could see from the console log that this.portfolios[0].portfolioInfo.portfolioTitle had the correct value when accessing from db, but that was because that was in the async await. The component was rendering before the async await was completed.

Adding an isLoaded variable managed in the created function and adding a v-if to the section solved the problem.

Thanks @Moritz Ringler